# JqGrid with subgrid and single XML file as input

Tags: jquery, xml, jqgrid

I have an XML file having a structure like this:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <id>P1</id>
        <name>PRODUCT 1</name>
        <accessories>
            <accessory>
                <id>acc_1</id>
                <name></name>
            </accessory>
            <accessory>
                <id>acc_2</id>
                <name></name>
            </accessory>
            <accessory>
                <id>acc_3</id>
                <name></name>
            </accessory>
        </accessories>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>P2</id>
        <name>PRODUCT 2</name>
        <accessories>
            <accessory>
                <id>acc_1</id>
                <name>ACC 1</name>
            </accessory>
            <accessory>
                <id>acc_2</id>
                <name>ACC 2</name>
            </accessory>            
        </accessories>
    </product>
</products>
```

I want to have **all products in a Grid** using jqGrid and the **accessories in a subgrid** for each product (with the plus icon).

For that I use the following js:

```
var myGrid = $("#prods").jqGrid({
    url: 'products.xml',
    datatype: "xml",
    colNames:["id", "Name"],
    colModel:[
        {name:"id",  key: true, index:"id", width:90, xmlmap:"id", sortable:true},
        {name:"Name", index:"Name", width:100, sortable:true, xmlmap:"name"}}
    ],
    width: 300,
    height:480,
    ignoreCase: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: true,
    sortname: 'Name',
    sortorder: "asc",
    sortable: true,
    pager: "#pager",                    
    xmlReader: {
        root: "products",
        row: "product",
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "sku",
        subgrid: {
            root: "products>product>accessories",
            row: "accessory",
            repeatitems:false,
            id: "id"
        }                           
    },
    caption: "Products",
    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: function(grid_id, row_id) {                     
        var subgrid_table_id;
        subgrid_table_id = grid_id + "_t";
        jQuery("#" + grid_id).html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table>");
        jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid( {
            colNames: [ 'Id', 'Name'],
            colModel: [
                {name:"accid",index:"accid",width:80, xmlmap:"id"},
                {name:"accname",index:"accname",width:80, xmlmap:"name"}
            ],
            height: 50,
            rowNum:10,                      
        });
    }   
});
```

It does not shows the subrecords. 
I tried also to put the same root / row in the subgrid as the parent grid and using the reference like this for the ID: "products>product>accessories>accessory>id" but it does not work as well.

Anybody have already found an example which works (in fact my data source is the same file for both grid/subgrid) like I want.

Hope this is clear enough, otherwise do not hesitate to comment for requesting more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Subgrids](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs#subgrids) feature of jqGrid is mostly provided for dynamically filled data. I mean, that on every click on the plus sign it will be made an `jQuery.ajax` call to get the data from the server. You want get get the whole grid and subgrid data in one XML response (in one XML file). For the case I can suggest you two alternative implementation ways.

The first one you can see live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubgridRuffp.htm). The second one [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubgridRuffp1.htm).

The first change which required in your grid is the usage of `xmlmap:">id"` and `xmlmap:">name"` instead of `xmlmap:"id"` and `xmlmap:"name"`. It is required because the XML data for the subgrid has the same XML element names like the main grid.

Now some comments to the code. The first version of the solution use `subGridUrl` with the same url like for the main grid. So to be able to read the correct part of the XML data I modify `xmlReader.subgrid.root` parameter of jqGrid on every subgrid expand (inside of [subGridBeforeExpand](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid#events)).

One can make the loading of products.xml file from the server even more quickly is one use local caching of the previous requests. To do this one either `prmNames: {nd:null,page:null,rows:null,sort:null,order:null,search:null}` parameter of jqGrid or `serializeGridData: function() { return ""; }` or `postData:""` which all remove all parameters sending to the server. To remove additional parameters from the GET request of the subgrid data I use `serializeSubGridData: function() {return "";}`.

The full code of the first solution is here:

```
$("#prods").jqGrid({
    url: 'products.xml',
    datatype: "xml",
    colNames:["id", "Name"],
    colModel:[
        {name:"id",   index:"id",   width:90,  xmlmap:">id", key: true},
        {name:"Name", index:"Name", width:100, xmlmap:">name"}
    ],
    width: 400,
    height:"100%",
    ignoreCase: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: true,
    sortname: 'Name',
    sortorder: "asc",
    sortable: true,
    pager: "#pager",
    xmlReader: {
        root: "products",
        row: "product",
        repeatitems: false,
        subgrid: {
            row: "accessory",
            repeatitems:false,
            id: "id"
        }
    },
    subGridBeforeExpand: function(pID, id) {
        this.p.xmlReader.subgrid.root =
            "products>product:has('id:contains('"+id+"')')>accessories";
    },
    caption: "Products",
    //serializeGridData: function() { return ""; },
    //prmNames: {nd:null,page:null,rows:null,sort:null,order:null,search:null},
    postData:"",
    serializeSubGridData: function() {
        // remove parameters like "nd_=1301502998517" and "id=P1"
        // appended to the url
        return "";
    },
    subGrid: true,
    subgridtype:'xml',
    subGridUrl:'products.xml',
    subGridModel:[
        {
            name : ['id','name'],
            width : [80,80] ,
            align : ['left','left']
        }
    ]
});
```

Another solution not use the `subgrid` part of `xmlReader` and just use the [subGridRowExpanded](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid#events) in the [Subgrid as grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid_as_grid) style, but I use `datatype:'xmlstring'` instead of `datatype:'xml'`. In the code below I use small trick that `datatype:'xmlstring'` accept not only strings as the value of the `datastr` parameter. Instead of that one can use pure XML parsed data. So I save the parsed XML data inside of `loadComplete` in an variable and then just use the previous saved parsed XML data.

The full code of the second solution is here:

```
var myXMLdata;
$("#prods").jqGrid({
    url: 'products.xml',
    datatype: "xml",
    colNames:["id", "Name"],
    colModel:[
        {name:"id",   index:"id",   width:90,  xmlmap:">id", key: true},
        {name:"Name", index:"Name", width:100, xmlmap:">name"}
    ],
    width: 400,
    height:"100%",
    ignoreCase: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    rownumbers:true,
    loadonce: true,
    sortname: 'Name',
    sortorder: "asc",
    sortable: true,
    pager: "#pager",
    xmlReader: {
        root: "products",
        row: "product",
        repeatitems: false
    },
    loadComplete: function(data) {
        // test whether we have initial loadind and the "data" has XML type
        if (data.nodeType) {
            myXMLdata = data; // save original XML data
        }
    },
    caption: "Products",
    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: function(grid_id, row_id) {
        var subgrid_table_id = grid_id + "_t";
        $("#" + grid_id).html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "''></table>");
        $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid( {
            colNames: ['Id', 'Name'],
            datatype:'xmlstring',
            datastr: myXMLdata,
            colModel: [
                {name:"accid",   index:"accid",   width:80, xmlmap:"id", key:true},
                {name:"accname", index:"accname", width:80, xmlmap:"name"}
            ],
            xmlReader: {
                root:"products>product:has('id:contains('"+row_id+"')')>accessories",
                row:">accessory",
                repeatitems: false
            },
            gridview:true,
            height: "100%",
            rowNum:1000
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. The second solution looks more elegant for my case. It works perfectly now.

Comment: @ruffp: You are welcome! I find the second way also better, but I included the first one to show why the `subgrid` part of `xmlReader` exists at all and how there can be used together with other parameters like `subGridUrl`, `subgridtype` and `subGridModel`. In your original code example you used a mix between both ways (`subGridRowExpanded` and `xmlReader.subgrid`). So with the example I tried to explain you more about the differences of the both approaches.

Comment: I do implementing same but with JSON. Let me try replacing datatype, datastr, and xmlReader to json, jsonstring & jsonreader and see. Thanks. It was very helpful!