# Send subgrid data back with initial grid data in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm looking at the jqGrid subgrid in the [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data) and I'm wondering if it's possible to send back the each subgrid's data in the json for the master grid data.

I'd like to only make one ajax call to retrieve all of the data for both the master and subgrids, forgoing the need for a subgridurl.

Is this possible with the default jsonReader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Subgrids](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#subgrids) has no support of loading whole data at once. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5489785/315935) I described two approaches how you can construct a workaround to implement what you need.

One more alternative would be to use some other feature of jqGrid like [TreeGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#tree_grid) or [Grouping](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping) instead of [subgrids](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#subgrids). See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6650281/315935) and [the next one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6676663/315935) for details.

Comment: You're right, `TreeGrid` is really what I need to use.  Thanks for breaking my tunnel vision.